# Finding Pricing tier of Azure SQL Server without access to the subscription but having admin login access

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have admin login access to an Azure SQL Server instance but it's not in my subscription. So I can't go to Azure page for this resource to find Pricing tier information. But I do have admin access to the SQL Server and can login to it using SSMS. Is there way I can find out **Pricing tier** of this SQL Server instance by running some command etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sys.database_service_objectives (Azure SQL Database)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-service-objectives-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current):

This example can be run on the master database or on Azure SQL Database user databases. The query returns the name, service, and performance tier information of the database(s).

```
SELECT  d.name,   
     slo.*    
FROM sys.databases d   
JOIN sys.database_service_objectives slo    
ON d.database_id = slo.database_id;
```

[image]

Hope this helps.